# Intent from widget not taken into account since Android SDK 31

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app offers the possibility to launch it through as many widgets as wanted by the user. To determine which widget trigerred the launch, I use an extra parameter in the Intent associated to the widget. This parameter is the widget id provided by the `update` function of my `AppWidgetProvider`.
As long as I target SDK version up to 30, everything is fine. If I try to target to Android SDK 31 or 32, when I add a new widget, I get the following error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vd63.utilitaires.memo: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

I have tried to declare my Intent mutable, as Intents were until now, as far as I have read, mutable by default. But when I click on the widget, the app reappears but doesn't take into account the Intent passed to the widget.
I tried to change the Intent to immutable, but without improvements.

Does anyone know the origin of this change in behaviour between Android SDK 31 and it's predecessors, and how to cope with it?

Edit : targetting SDK 30 doesn't remove the problem when the app is running on a device whose OS is Android 12. Targetting SDK 32 is neither a problem when running on an Android 8 device.

Answer (score 1):

This issue came since sdk 31 currently i am handling it with this condition in my project.

Kotlin solution

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets Android 12 or higher, you must specify the mutability of each PendingIntent object that your app creates. To declare that a given PendingIntent object is mutable or immutable, use the PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE flag, respectively.

You'll need to declare if your `PendingIntent` is im/mutable in the `PendingIntent` passed to `setPendingIntentTemplate` and/or `setOnClickPendingIntent` (I think you need mutable).

In most cases, your app should create immutable PendingIntent objects:

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext,
        REQUEST_CODE, intent,
        /* flags */ PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

If a PendingIntent object is immutable, then other apps cannot modify the intent to adjust the result of invoking the intent.
Mutable PendingIntent is needed when:

1. Supporting direct reply actions in notifications.
2. Associating notifications with the Android Auto framework, using instances of CarAppExtender.
3. Placing conversations in bubbles using instances of PendingIntent.
4. Requesting device location information by calling requestLocationUpdates() or similar APIs.
5. Scheduling alarms using AlarmManager.

for more info [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent)